# Counting number of visible li items within a div with none display

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a div which is hidden and then I am also hiding li using  jquery show and hide, now problem is that I am not able to count it properly,

Here is an example

List Item
List Item Hidden

when i use jQuery hide, and then use alert to count number of hidden li items, it doesn't count right,

```
 alert($("li:not(.hidden)").size());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/76NNp/24/

Answer (score 2):

Change `.hidden` to **[`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)**

```
alert($("li:not(:hidden)").length);
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/76NNp/21/)</kbd>

```
alert($("li:not(:hidden)").size());
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/76NNp/23/)</kbd>

while using `.hidden` it will select `li` that doesn't have class `hidden` that's why it returns 3

Comment: sorry but div display is none, and by mistake i didn't changed it in fiddle before, find latest fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/76NNp/24/